# C# ProcessStartInfo and Process.Start cannot find programs in System32

Tags: c#

I'm trying to run a shell command with elevated permisions in C#. However the following code returns:

*The system cannot find the file specified.*

```
string command = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "wdsutil.exe");
string args = ""; //Appropriate arguments
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
psInfo.Arguments = args;
psInfo.Verb = "runas";

try
{
    Process p = Process.Start(psInfo);
    p.WaitForExit();
    return "Try Done";
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    return e.Message;
}
```

The error exists without the SystemDriectory prefixed as well.

However, the command does not return the error if I execute the command *C:\wdsutil* (or any other command in C:).

How do I get Process.Start to run these commands in System32

Comment: What is `Environment.SystemDirectory` returning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

system32 is on newer systems (esp. 64 Bit windows 7 or 2008) not "real"... it is synthezied from some internal directories and when it is accessed it shows different apps (32 vs. 64) different content...

Comment: Thanks! This was pretty much what I had to do to fix it.


See: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942589]() (Says XP, is applicable for Server 2008, the OS I am on)


_The long answer is to use C:\Windows\Sysnative as the directory instead_

Answer (score -1):

I test ran the code, changing the executable to one that I located in C:\Windows\System32 directory. It runs ok. (I am running Win 7 64 Bit)

> Suggestion: Make sure that the exe is present in the
>   C:\Windows\System32, or wherever you are trying to run it from. Also, make sure it is unblocked if you'd downloaded it from the internet (Right click the exe > Properties > Unblock).

```
        string command = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "wscript.exe");
        string args1 = ""; //Appropriate arguments
        ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(command);
        psInfo.Arguments = args1;
        psInfo.Verb = "runas";

        try
        {
            Process p = Process.Start(psInfo);
            p.WaitForExit();
            //return "Try Done";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //return e.Message;
        }
```

Comment: It's actually in C:\Windows\System32 and it was not downloaded from the internet (installed off a Microsoft distributed CD)